# What kind of soil should I used for Indoor Plant

Tags: indoors, soil

**What kind of soil should I used for Indoor Plant ?**

> I planted some plants last year but due to wet soil fungus/mold was growing in soil, so I don’t want it now. coco peat or soil which one is best for indoor plants.

Comment: What do you mean by soil? Do you mean soil from the garden, or do you mean something like potting soil from a store-bought bag? A lot of people seem to like ProMix for most purposes. I just use some random indoor potting soil (make sure it's marked for indoors) with lots of extra perlite I add myself. I've never tried coco peat (so, I can't say). What kind of plants are you growing?

Comment: Yes, what kind of indoor plants?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would go for the purpose made potting mix from garden centres

Answer (score 1):

It's vary greatly upon the type of your plant. In general, most of the indoor plants show well grown-up in soil that have-

- good enough system to flow out extra water.
- and low to mid range of nutritional elements.

Well, Coco peat can be a good option in maximum cases. But yeah, the exact plant profile can make it easier to provide accurate answer.